# fsockopen() error during registration in Opencart

Tags: php, email, opencart2.x, fsockopen

First the mail notifications wont work in OpenCart 2.0.2.0. I tried using gmail smtp and tried login registering, this is the error message. I got:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/spicycom/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 168Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to :465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/spicycom/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 168Notice: Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) in /home/spicycom/public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 171

Please how do I fix this problem.

This is the mail code snipet

> ```
> <?php
> class Mail {
> protected $to;
> protected $from;
> protected $sender;
> protected $replyto;
> protected $subject;
> protected $text;
> protected $html;
> protected $attachments = array();
> public $protocol = 'mail';
> public $smtp_hostname;
> public $smtp_username;
> public $smtp_password;
> public $smtp_port = 25;
> public $smtp_timeout = 5;
> public $newline = "\n";
> public $verp = false;
> public $parameter = '';
> ```

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}

public function setTo($to) {
    $this->to = $to;
}

public function setFrom($from) {
    $this->from = $from;
}

public function setSender($sender) {
    $this->sender = $sender;
}

public function setReplyTo($reply_to) {
    $this->replyto = $reply_to;
}

public function setSubject($subject) {
    $this->subject = $subject;
}

public function setText($text) {
    $this->text = $text;
}

public function setHtml($html) {
    $this->html = $html;
}

public function addAttachment($filename) {
    $this->attachments[] = $filename;
}

public function send() {
    if (!$this->to) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail to required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->from) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail from required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->sender) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail sender required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->subject) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail subject required!');
        exit();
    }

    if ((!$this->text) && (!$this->html)) {
        trigger_error('Error: E-Mail message required!');
        exit();
    }

    if (!$this->replyto) {
        $this->setReplyTo($this->sender);
    }

    if (is_array($this->to)) {
        $to = implode(',', $this->to);
    } else {
        $to = $this->to;
    }

    $boundary = '----=_NextPart_' . md5(time());

    $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $this->newline;

    if ($this->protocol != 'mail') {
        $header .= 'To: ' . $to . $this->newline;
        $header .= 'Subject: ' . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this-    >    subject) . '?=' . $this->newline;
    }

    $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'From: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->replyto) . '?=' . ' <' . $this->from . '>' . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . $this->newline;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

    if (!$this->html) {
        $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
    } else {
        $message  = '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '_alt"' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;

        if ($this->text) {
            $message .= $this->text . $this->newline;
        } else {
            $message .= 'This is a HTML email and your email client software does not support HTML email!' . $this->newline;
        }

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= $this->html . $this->newline;
        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt--' . $this->newline;
    }

    foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
        if (file_exists($attachment)) {
            $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

            $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

            fclose($handle);

            $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . '>' . $this->newline;
            $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachment)) . $this->newline . $this->newline;
            $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        }
    }

    $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $this->newline;

    if ($this->protocol == 'mail') {
        ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->from);

        if ($this->parameter) {
            mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
        } else {
            mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);
        }
    } elseif ($this->protocol == 'smtp') {
        $tls = substr($this->smtp_hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls';
        $hostname = $tls ? substr($this->smtp_hostname, 6) : $this->smtp_hostname;

        $handle = fsockopen($hostname, $this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout);

        if (!$handle) {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')');
            exit();
        } else {
            if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                socket_set_timeout($handle, $this->smtp_timeout, 0);
            }

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            if ($tls) {
                fputs($handle, 'STARTTLS' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 220) {
                    trigger_error('Error: STARTTLS not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                stream_socket_enable_crypto($handle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
            }

            if (!empty($this->smtp_username)  && !empty($this->smtp_password)) {
                fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, 'AUTH LOGIN' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                    trigger_error('Error: AUTH LOGIN not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                    trigger_error('Error: Username not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }

                fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 235) {
                    trigger_error('Error: Password not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                fputs($handle, 'HELO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    trigger_error('Error: HELO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            }

            if ($this->verp) {
                fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
            } else {
                fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . "\r\n");
            }

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            if (!is_array($this->to)) {
                fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $this->to . '>' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                    trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($this->to as $recipient) {
                    fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $recipient . '>' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                        trigger_error('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                        exit();
                    }
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, 'DATA' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 354) {
                trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            // According to rfc 821 we should not send more than 1000 including the CRLF
            $message = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $header . $message);
            $message = str_replace("\r", "\n", $message);

            $lines = explode("\n", $message);

            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                $results = str_split($line, 998);

                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                        fputs($handle, $result . "\r\n");
                    } else {
                        fputs($handle, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $result) . "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            fputs($handle, '.' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                trigger_error('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            fputs($handle, 'QUIT' . "\r\n");

            $reply = '';

            while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                $reply .= $line;

                if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 221) {
                trigger_error('Error: QUIT not accepted from server!');
                exit();
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Please provide some code snippets!

Comment: I just did now. thanks